# How to open all offsite links in a new window except for specific href?

Tags: javascript

On my site, I have some links that are built dynamically with JS. Not all of them contain an href value, so I add an href value dynamically. I use `javascript:;` as that value.

Now, I need to be able to open all links not on my host in a new window. Obviously, `javascript:;` is not my host, so any link with that in the href attribute will open in a new window.

In the snippet below, I'm trying to prevent that from happening, but I'm not getting the result I desire.

**How do I push all offsite links to a new tab, except for one that I specify?**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a:not(a[href])").forEach(element => {
  element.setAttribute("href", "javascript:;")
});

var all_links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0; i < all_links.length; i++) {
  var a = all_links[i];
  if (a.hostname != location.hostname || a.getAttribute("href") !== 'javascript:;') {
    a.rel = 'noopener';
    a.target = '_blank';
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>
<hr>
<a>something else</a>
```

Comment: Why overthink this use  `target="_blank"` attribute to your links (anchor tags). Now when your visitors click that link, it will open in a new window or tab (depending on which web browser they are using and how they configured that browser).

Comment: Because you don't know how many link I have on my site. It's much easier to manage everything at once than to manage thousands of links individually.

Comment: BUT you said you generated them dynamically so do it on the generate?  Not trying  to quibble but more trying to understand that part of the issue.

Comment: Why are you adding `href` attributes (eg `href="javascript:;"`) to anchors that don't need them?

Comment: @phil You deleted your answer, but I thought we were on the right track. I'm trying to open all links (not on my host) in a new window. All links that are part of my site (`href="/path/to/page"`) should open in the same window. All links that are built with `href="javascript:;"` should also open in the same window.

Comment: I deleted my answer because your question needs more clarity. Again, why are you adding `href` attributes / properties to those anchors?

Comment: @Phil - this site was built many years ago before my time. In order to achieve a focus state on some of the anchors on the site, I had to dynamically add `href="javascript:;"` on anchors where it didn't exist. It's a completely separate issue, but that's where it started.

Comment: Sounds like you should just use CSS for that instead of adding redundant attributes. `a:not([href]) { cursor: pointer; }` for example

Comment: My site has hundreds of thousands of links. They are built over 15 years and not all are equal. I think the logic is simple. If it's an external link - open in a new tab. If it's anything else or `href="javascript:;"`, then open in the same tab. I'm just having a hard time putting it together.

Comment: @phil Are you disagreeing with the logic here? I'm only trying to clean up a mess that took 15 years to make. I'm not trying to move mountains.

Comment: I just don't understand why you're adding attributes that make your main task more difficult

Comment: I'm adding attributes because there are many anchor tags (thousands) on my site that don't have an `href` attached. Without an href, I can't focus them (accessibility reasons). A lot of work has already gone into the focus states on our site, so I can't go near that. I just need to account for links with `href='javascript:;'` and make sure they open in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was the best solution...

If you inspect each link, you'll see that the external link has `_blank`, the internal link has `_self`, and the one with `href="javascript:;"` has `_self`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a:not(a[href])").forEach(element => {
  element.setAttribute("href", "javascript:;")
});

let all_links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for (var i = 0; i < all_links.length; i++) {
  let anchors = all_links[i];
  if (anchors.getAttribute('href') == 'javascript:;' || anchors.hostname == location.hostname) {
    anchors.target = "_self";
  } else {
    anchors.target = "_blank";
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://yahoo.com">External Link (Yahoo!)</a>
<hr>
<a href="/questions/69563273/change-the-font-and-the-line-spacing-of-a-style">Change the font and the line spacing of a style (SO Question)</a>
<hr>
<a>anchor without href (Goes nowhere)</a>
```